# Possible to sum several intervals without using multiple sumifs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am putting together a financial statement in Excel where I get my data from a trial balance that has a column with account numbers (named 'Account') and a column with amounts (named 'Amount').

For the line item revenue in the financial statement I want the sum of the amounts that are booked in the accounts numbered from 3199 to 3990. I use the formula: 
SUMIFS(Amount, Account, ">=3199"; Account; "<=3990") 
And this works perfectly.

However, for the line item cost of sales I have several account intervals. I want the sum of the accounts 7210-7299 and 7336-7394 and, ..., etc. If I use SUMIFS(Amount, Account, ">=7210", Account, "<=7299", Account, ">=7336", Account, "<=7394), it will return zero as these are overlapping criterias. I can of course put each account interval in a seperate SUMIF-formula. But is there a less tedious way I can do this? Is there a way to treat each interval  seperately/isolated in the same formula?

Comment: The `and, ..., etc.` part of your description throws a lot of ambiguity into your question. There are a couple ways to do this, some with and some without multiple SUMIFS. The right method will depend on what **exactly** you are looking for.

Comment: the "and, .... , etc". is just a bunch of more account intervals such as 7401-7420, 7455-7500, 7622-7699. And I want the corresponding amounts booked in those accounts summed into the line item cost of sales, without using a SUMIF for each account interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Simple `SUMPRODUCT` with multiple criteria fixes the issue:*

[image]

- Formual in Cell `C48`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(((B$33:B$47>=7210)*(B$33:B$47<=7299)+(B$33:B$47>=7336)*(B$33:B$47<=7394))*(C$33:C$47))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Multiple criteria for the same Column needs `+` sign.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Nice! I only had to put the column with amounts as the second array, if not I would get #VALUE

Comment: Glad to hep you @franke,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your account structure here are a couple of tips to possibly shrink your formula:

use wildcards: `...`Account,"72*"`...`

use an array (with sum wrap): `sum(sumifs(..., Account, {"72*", "73*"})`

Hope this gives you some ideas.

--- edit ---

Additionally, you could just create a helper column to that has the account groupings, then sumifs using the helper column.

--- edit 2 ---
just saw your header of no multiple sumifs so moved this down here for others to see

use multiple sumifs: `sumifs(...)+sumifs(...)` or `sum(...)-sumifs(...)`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the account structure is such that between account no 7299 and 7336 there are accounts that belongs to wages. But nice tip!

Given my account structure, I think the help column might just be my best option...

Answer (score 0):

Put the pairs of upper and lower limits into a pair of hard-coded arrays and SUM the SUMIFS.

```
 =SUM(SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ">="&{7210,7336}, A:A, "<="&{7299,7394}))
                             ^^^^ ^^^^              ^^^^ ^^^^
                         lower boundaries        upper boundaries
```

Add another set (e.g. 8000-8200) like this,

```
 =SUM(SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ">="&{7210,7336,8000}, A:A, "<="&{7299,7394,8200}))
```

Comment: Nice, did not know this.

Comment: Caveat: this only works with hard-coded values in a `{..., ...}` array (note that they are wrapped in math braces, not conventional brackets). You cannot reference cells in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

**Formula**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Account_Number, okAccounts, Value))
```

Where

- `Account_Number` is the list of account numbers
- `okAccounts` is a range that holds every account number you want to include in your sum
- `Value` is the list of values that correspond to `Account_Number`

**How it works**

Because `okAccounts` is a range, SUMIF evaluates for every cell in the range. It returns an array of values for each cell in `okAccounts`. `SUMPRODUCT()` accepts an array as input, and returns the sum of all of the array values. You'll see this in action if you use the Evaluate Formula tool on the formula.

[image: SUMPRODUCT SUMIF]

The only downside of this approach is that you need to enumerate every valid account number, but I think it's easier than building complicated lists of valid ranges.

I used [FormulaChop](https://formulachop.com/) to write this example formula and generate this screenshot. (Full Disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop).

**Edit**

I thought about it more and realized it would be nice to have a formula to enumerate all of the values in a range. So I wrote one:

```
=IF(Range_Start+(ROW() - ROW(First_Cell)) <= Range_End, Range_Start+(ROW() - ROW(First_Cell)), "")
```

Where

- `Range_Start` is the start of the range (e.g. `7210`)
- `Range_End` is the end of the range (e.g. `7299`)
- `First_Cell` is the locked address of the first cell in the column of enumerated values

[image: Enumerate Values]